# Print on the same line; mantain until replaced by new string

Tags: python

I want to write a function that will output a message on a console line. The message should remain until I don't call the same function again with a new message. At that point, the new message should appear on the same line of the old message replacing it.

```
import sys
from time import sleep

def printSameLine(my_message):

    sys.stdout.write("Message: %s   \r" % (my_message))
    sys.stdout.flush()

    return

for i in range(1,10):

    printSameLine(str(i))
    sleep(4)
```

This doesn't seem to obtain the desired result

Comment: the code seems correct, from my understanding of the problem. explain what is "the desired result"

Comment: just change `sys.stdout.write("Message: %s   \r" % (my_message))` to `sys.stdout.write("\rMessage: %s" % (my_message))`.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.stdout.flush` does not clear the line - it clears the buffer (in other words prints everything on the line). What you can do is print a long string of `\b` to clear the current line, but it won't go back over newlines either. Try:

```
sys.stdout.write('\b'*100)
sys.stdout.write("Message: %s   \r" % (my_message))
```

Else, you should also get good results with just putting the `\r` at the start of your write:

```
sys.stdout.write("\rMessage: %s" % (my_message))
```

But this will not nice if your newer message is shorter than the earlier:

```
sys.stdout.write("Hi there")
sys.stdout.write("\r12")
#Output is 
12 there
```

Comment: `sys.stdout.write("\rMessage: %s" % (my_message))` doesn't seem to work. It prints one message every two loops...

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay to use the print statement you can obtain the desired result in python 3.x by:

```
print("Message " + my_message + "\r", end='')
```

or append an comma in python 2:

```
print "Message " + my_message + "\r",
```

So you can basically do:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

def printSameLine(my_message):
     print("Message: %s   \r" % (my_message), end='')
     return

for i in range(1,10):
    printSameLine(str(i))
    sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alos just clear the console with following code before calling print with updated message. However if you have other lines with information in console you would have to reprint them all as well.

```
os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
```

Comment: Don't think that's what the OP asked.

Comment: @SiHa From what I understood OP wants to have the updated message appear on the same line in his console. If so then clearing console and reprinting updated message would give desired 'visual' effect.

Comment: It's a bit drastic though - there may be other information on the console already.

Comment: @SiHa unfortunately it is a bit crude and in case of more than one line being outputted forces you to implement print_to_console(updated_values) or such to rebuild whole 'view'